# Entity framework does not fetching all records

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

In my MVC web application, I am using Entity Framework for fetching database record, But it's going to return only single record. Even I checked it using debugger but debugger does not hit DAL of code.

Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AllLandLord(User_Master usermaster, CityDate citydate)
    {

        List<User_Master> allLandLord = new List<User_Master>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            allLandLord = agreementnewBAL.AllLandLordUsers();
            return PartialView("LoadLandLord", allLandLord);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("LoadLandLord", allLandLord);
        }
    }
```

In ViewModel

```
public List<User_Master> AllLandLordUsers()
    {
        List<User_Master> allLandLord = new List<User_Master>();
        allLandLord = addnewmanager.FetchUsers(agreementnew);
        //Debugger.Break();

        return allLandLord;
    }
```

In DAL For fetching records

```
public List<User_Master> FetchUsers(AgreementNew agreementnew)
    {
        RentalAgreementEntities db = new RentalAgreementEntities();
        User_Master us = new User_Master();
    //Debugger.Break();

        return (db.User_Master.SqlQuery("SELECT *,CASE WHEN US_Gender='M' THEN 'Male' WHEN US_Gender='F' THEN 'Female' ELSE '' END US_Gender FROM User_Master WHERE US_SerialNo < 3", "")).ToList();

    }
```

When I run above query seperately in SQL Server Editor, It gives three records. But in application it returns only one record when run.  Also when I add breakpoints anywhere in `FetchUsers(AgreementNew agreementnew)`, it doesn't hit breakpoint when debugging.  So, How do I fetch all records using above query using EF?

Comment: Did you try debugging this whole action? If no breakpoint is hit in FetchUsers, how can you know that this query is even executed?

Comment: Hello raderick, It works perfectly now after restarting my visual studio editor